# Toggle() don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to use the function toggle() to change a class each click, but this function just hide the element selected

```
    $( "#bills-menu" ).toggle(function() {
       $("#bills-menu > .fa-sort-desc").removeClass("fa-sort-desc").addClass("fa-sort-asc");
}, function() {
       $("#bills-menu > .fa-sort-asc").removeClass("fa-sort-asc").addClass("fa-sort-desc");
  });
```

Comment: which version of `JQuery` you are using?

Comment: seriously? http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: for FYI, The `toggle()` method was deprecated in `jQuery` version `1.8`, and removed in version `1.9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the snippet below which uses the [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) JQuery function. You can also check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/OjrMGY)**. I hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-sort-asc");
  });
})
```

```css
#bills-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="bills-menu">
  <span class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, I was using a last jquery version

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned the .toggle() function actually does that (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), displays or hide the element.

You might get away with doing something a little different, depending on how are you calling that function... you could try using the toggleClass() method instead (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Let me know if you need any more clarification, I would provide a code sample but I figured you should probably look at that documentation first and update the question if that helps.